# Insert Row in sharepoint list form newform using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, csom, jquery-ui

How to add a tr in between rows in share point Newform using jquery? Attached is the DOM of my sharepoint form.[image]

. I tried like this but it inserts inside the inner table of the form

```
var attachHTML='<tr><td width="190" height="15" class="ms-formlabel" valign="top">Attach File</td><td height="15" class="ms-formbody" id="attachmentsOnClient" valign="bottom"><span dir="ltr"><input name="fileupload0" title="Name" class="ms-fileinput" id="onetidIOFile" type="file" size="56"></span></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="attachOKbutton" onclick="OkAttach()" type="button" value="Attach"><span class="ms-SpaceBetButtons" id="idSpace"></span><input class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="attachCancelButton" accesskey="C" onclick="CancelAttach()" type="button" value="Cancel"></td></tr>';
    var closetrow=$("[id^='Proposed_x0020_End_x0020_date_x0_']").closest('tr');
        $('.ms-formtable  tbody').find(closetrow[1] ).after(attachHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working like below

```
    var attachHTML='<tr><td width="190" height="15" class="ms-formlabel" valign="top">Attach File</td><td height="15" class="ms-formbody" id="attachmentsOnClient" valign="bottom"><span dir="ltr"><input name="fileupload0" title="Name" class="ms-fileinput" id="onetidIOFile" type="file" size="56"></span></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="attachOKbutton" onclick="OkAttach()" type="button" value="Attach"><span class="ms-SpaceBetButtons" id="idSpace"></span><input class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="attachCancelButton" accesskey="C" onclick="CancelAttach()" type="button" value="Cancel"></td></tr>';
var closetrow=$("[id^='Proposed_x0020_End_x0020_date_'][Id$='DateTimeFieldTopTable']").closest('tr');
    $('.ms-formtable  tbody').find(closetrow).after(attachHTML);
```